# code for filtering handsontables

Tags: filter, handsontable

Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309993/anyway-to-filter-rows-with-handsontable)

ZekeDroid wrotes:

From here out to hide the non-matched rows, it gets tough. What I did was write a simple function that.

But grabbing the web for some hours I didn't found any code.

I will present just a readonly table but with many rows. And I have no idea how to write a plug-in by myself.

to be more specific:
You discussed the filter problem on February with Micheael B and you wrote
that you has wrote a little code using the search plugin. And it seems to me
that Michael has used it with some problems.

And in turn it seems to me that Michael has access to your code, even there is no link in your answer. I'm searching the wwww (the whole world wide web) - but found nothing.

So my main question is: can you show me your code?

My request: I want to filter (shows only) the rows which match the search
criteria. To colorize the matched cells is only a nice-to-have. Only
colorizing as in the handsontable examples is not really meaningful if
there are 2 hits and the table has 1000 rows.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What do you need exactly? What is your question?

Comment: Ah, you want the code that does the "filter" operation. It's highly specialized to my project but with what I suggested you should be able to implement it yourself. What have you tried?

Comment: that's not very constructive

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39769474/5898393) which is similar to this one but I also wanted to filter the column individually.

I did manage to code a solution that you will find in my own Q/A.

So in your case, if you want the code that hide the irrelevant row(s) based on **one search criteria** , the main function will look like this :

```
function filter(search) {
    var row, r_len;
    var data = myData;
    var array = [];
    for (row = 0, r_len = data.length; row < r_len; row++) {
        for(col = 0, c_len = data[row].length; col < c_len; col++) {
            if(('' + data[row][col]).toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1) {
                array.push(data[row]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    hot.loadData(array);
}
```

Find the complete solution in [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpLm7f2k/)