# Providing custom options to Handsontable filter_by_value

Tags: javascript, filter, handsontable

I'm evaluating the pro version of [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/) that comes with a [filter feature](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.3.3/demo-filtering.html). Enabling filtering by value, the library provides options for all values available for a column (e.g., if a column holds numbers from 1 to 10, it would provide 10 options: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).

As I'm loading chunks of data from a remote server, the library is not able to determine all distinct values that exist for a column. For example, given a table with a column showing booleans (false, true), the first page might only show *false* for this column, which results in the filter showing "false" as the only option to filter this column. Here I would like to provide options to filter this column by value: true, false. Is this possible with Handsontable?

Comment: Surprisingly, it doesn't seem there is any function to change those values. I tried to search in the [ItemsFactory](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.11.0/ItemsFactory.html) of the [DropdownMenu](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.11.0/DropdownMenu.html) instance but no luck. However, I'm sure you could achieve this more easily with custom functions instead of using the Pro version. [See this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28309993/5898393) for a custom filtering function. I'm sure it won't be hard to create a simple dropdown alongside with the search fields.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'd like to use the "filter_by_condition" of the pro version, hence I'd like to add the functionality of "filter_by_value" but with customized options. Here, I'd like to stick with the design of the filter offered by Handsontable instead of building a custom one.

Comment: If you want to stick with the Pro version, it doesn't cost anything to ask them directly on their forum for such a function. As I said in my first comment, I'm very surprised that it doesn't exist knowing all the options / instances / methods already available.