# Approach to create column filter in handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Please help me out in guiding how to modify handsontable according to below image.
I have to use existing functionality of filters and try to create something similar to below image.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660820/5898393.

Comment: thanks for the link, but how i will add these filter column in the handsontable i am not able to figure out, will it be part of thead or tbody, any advice is appreciated.