# Handsontable - Custom Operation of 'Filter By Value' In Filter Menu

Tags: handsontable

I have added the filter option to a handsontable instance I have constructed. And the filters load and operate correctly. As per the instructions in the following link:

https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.12.0/demo-filtering.html

However, the issue I am having is that the 'Filter by value' function in the filter menu is not very intuitive and confusing to some of our users.

For example. If you look at the demo in the above link, open the filter menu for column A, then type 'Lorem' in the 'Filter by value' field and finally click OK. Nothing happens. You would think that it would just filter by all the values containing 'Lorem'.

But if you first click 'Clear', then type in 'Lorem', then click on the checkbox next to the 'Lorem' value the filter will work. See screenshot below clarifying these problems.

[image: Confusing Filtering]

Is there any way to make it operate so I can say type 'Lor' in the filter by value field, then just click OK to remove all of these other tedious steps? Much in the way that a excel filter on a column would work.

Comment: A live filter would be much better that's for sure. Unfortunately, I tried multiple time to search if there was any way to modify the function in this menu but no luck everytime. That's why I coded [my own filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660820/5898393) at some point... just sharing in case you're interested in an alternative solution.

Comment: @fab thanks for the suggestion. However, I would like to have this live filtering within the filter menus for each column. I have logged a feature request with the Handsontable team and I am awaiting a response from them if they can do anything for me!

Comment: Well, if they do, that would be fantastic !

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am giving here is not elegant, but it works …

The idea is to add the functionality of the "Clear All" link before filtering the list of values, and the functionality of the "Select All" link after filtering. All I did was add the code of the `onClearAllClick` and `onSelectAllClick` functions to the `onInput` function, with minor edits.

```
onInput(event) {
    /* code from onClearAllClick */
    const changesForClear = [];
    (0, _array.arrayEach)(this.itemsBox.getSourceData(), (row, rowIndex) => {
        row.checked = false;
        changesForClear.push((0, _data.dataRowToChangesArray)(row, rowIndex)[0]);
    });
    this.itemsBox.setSourceDataAtCell(changesForClear);
    /* end of code from onClearAllClick */
    const value = event.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase(this.getLocale());
    let filteredItems;
    if (value === '') {
        filteredItems = [...this.items];
    } else {
        filteredItems = (0, _array.arrayFilter)(this.items, item => `${item.value}`.toLocaleLowerCase(this.getLocale()).indexOf(value) >= 0);
    }
    this.itemsBox.loadData(filteredItems);
    /* code from onSelectAllClick */
    const changesForSelectAll = [];
    (0, _array.arrayEach)(this.itemsBox.getSourceData(), (row, rowIndex) => {
        row.checked = true;
        changesForSelectAll.push((0, _data.dataRowToChangesArray)(row, rowIndex)[0]);
    });
    this.itemsBox.setSourceDataAtCell(changesForSelectAll);
    /* end of code from onSelectAllClick */
}
```

All edits are made in the file **handsontable.full.js**.